# How to let the user delete a profile using php?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I currently have a website where the user can add profiles of people they know on a contacts page. I'm now trying to also let them delete specific profiles but I can't get it to work. Here's what I have so far.

Version 2.0 after feedback (now working):

```
  <form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method = "POST">
    profile = <input type = "text" name = "profile" required />
    <input type = "submit" />
  </form>

<?php

  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "root";
  $dbname = "registration";

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

   if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   } 

  $prepped = $conn->prepare ('DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ?'); 
  $prepped->bind_param ('i', $_POST["profile"]); 
    if ($prepped->execute()) {
      // success
    } else {
      // failure
    }

  var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

Comment: what is your input values for input name="profile"?

Comment: potentially scope for lots of problems here - one such issue would be the possibility of deleting any user not just one known to your user. `$_PHP_SELF` should be `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` but should be avoided - simply omit the action of same page.

Comment: @Ashu the input values for "profile" are just numbers, here I want the user to input an id number so that the profile with that specific id number can be deleted.

Comment: @RamRaider so I should rather replace it with the name of the page it is currently in?

Comment: How are you translating the variable `profile` here `WHERE id= profile";
`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't really know how to translate a variable, maybe that's what is going wrong

Comment: That is the reason you cannot get your code to work. Perhaps studying up on some PHP basics would help you?

Answer (score 2):

The query you're executing is literally looking for an id "profile" in the database.  Presumably the ID column is numeric so it can't possibly contain any rows with an id of "profile".

You need to pass the ID you want to delete in as a parameter to your query

```
$prepped = $conn->prepare ('DELETE FROM uses WHERE id = ?'); // The "?" is a placeholder that MySQL will replace with the specified parameter
$prepped->bind_param ('i', $_POST["profile"]); // 'i' indicates we're expecting an integer.  See PHP docs for other options
if ($prepped->execute()) {
    // The query executed without any errors (though you should also check how many rows were affected at this point to determine if anything was actually deleted)
} else {
    // Failure
}
```

Additionally your form markup is incorrect and therefore probably not posting to the correct location.

```
<form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method = "POST">
    Profile = <input type = "text" name = "profile" required />
    <input type = "submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Well I'm not getting any more error messages now but it still doesn't delete anything

Comment: Make sure that $_POST contains a valid value for profile.

Comment: Can I just put any number in there as long as it's linked to a profile, like 5?

Comment: So long as a row with an ID of the specified value exists in your table then it should be deleted, yes.  But that's assuming that you're actually posting a valid ID.  Please try doing some debugging, even if it's as simple as ```var_dump($_POST);```

Comment: I'm sorry but it just isn't deleting anything, now I'm getting this:  array(1) { ["profile"]=> &string(1) "5" }

Comment: And 5 is the number I typed in the form

Comment: Sorry but now it's getting too hard to debug it from here without knowing what your code, DB schema, etc are like.  One last thing, what happens if you manually run the query ```DELETE FROM uses WHERE id = 5``` from an SQL client (or even from your PHP script)?

Comment: If I run it manually it works, then it deletes the given user. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: SOLVED IT! After looking at the code for about an hour I realized I was linking to the wrong database all along... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look more like:

```
$query = sprintf("DELETE FROM uses WHERE id = '%s'", $profile);
```

or without `sprintf()`:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM uses WHERE id = '" . $profile . "'";
```

**EDIT after comments**

`$profile` is a variable holding the string with the name / id / whatever you use to profile the user. From your form, you should define it in this way:

```
$profile = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["profile"]);
```

of course before the query.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Let's not teach/propagate sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: Downvoted due to how utterly dangerous this code is.  It opens up an SQL injection vulnerability and should under no circumstances be suggested as a solution to pretty much any problem.  Please re-write your answer with an example that uses prepared statements, or at the very least does some string escaping

Comment: Sorry, but that is NO BETTER!  stripslashes only even exists to deal with PHP's 'magic' quotes 'feature', which no longer exists, and htmlspecialchars has nothing to do with making a string safe for SQL.

Comment: @GordonM are you referring to the use of [mysqli::real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)? Sorry if my security lacks, I am also still learning php and mysql too.

Comment: Yes, you should definitely be using that instead (or better yet, prepared/parameterised statements)

Answer (score -1):

- form action should be `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`
- see your code also.. what you are doing is passing the unknown `$sql` variable in if statement `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)`
  you have to pass `$query` variable defined above in this statement

Kindly replace your code with this code.. hope it will work for you :) goodluck

```
 <form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method = "POST">
     Profile = <input type = "text" name = "profile" required />
     <input type = "submit" />
  </form>

<?php

  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "root";
  $dbname = "registration";

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

   if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   ///////////NEW CODE///////////
    $profile_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['profile']);

    $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id= '".$profile_id."'";

    if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
      echo "Profile deleted successfully";
    } else {
      echo "Error deleting profile: " . $conn->error;
    }
   //////////////////////////////


?>
```

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string no longer exists as of PHP 7.  I suspect you meant the mysqli equivalent.  Also, while this is better than nothing I'd recommend you look into how to use parameterised statements instead of using string escaping.

Comment: Let's not teach/propagate sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: Along with what @GordonM said, you cannot mix MySQL API's

Comment: Don't use this code @Centaurius, it is wrong and dangerous.

Comment: @GordonM person is not telling us which version of php is he using.. and yeah its mysqli_real_escape_string . thank you for correcting me..